# Speed up NHibernate Calls to Oracle?

Tags: oracle, nhibernate

Are there any optimizations to consider when connecting to Oracle with NHibernate? My calls to Oracle are taking an extremely long time. If I run the NHibernate query (copied from my output window in Visual Studio) directly against Oracle, it comes right back in under a second. Here is my config file for NHibernate. I can post the mapping files if needed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-configuration xmlns="urn:nhibernate-configuration-2.2">
    <session-factory name="DefaultSessionFactory">
        <property name="connection.provider">NHibernate.Connection.DriverConnectionProvider</property>
        <property name="dialect">NHibernate.Dialect.OracleDialect</property>
        <property name="connection.driver_class">NHibernate.Driver.OracleClientDriver</property>
        <property name="connection.connection_string">Data Source=****;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=******;Password=*******;Unicode=True</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping assembly="AQTool.BL"/>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Update:
summarizing all the discussion here:

If I remove all the many-to-one relationships and just run my unit test against the single entity with no joins, the query still runs for over 2 minutes. If I copy the sql generated by nhibernate and run it directly against oracle, the query returns in under a second. I am posting my mapping file here as well. Is there anything I am missing that might be causing this disparity? The only thing I am doing is selecting by Account Id. Although the table is large (over 5M rows), the customer account id field is indexed, and the raw query comes back very quickly.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" namespace="AQTool.BL" assembly="AQTool.BL" default-lazy="true">
    <class name="AQTool.BL.EmailAddress,AQTool.BL" table="EMAIL_CUSTOMER_ADDRESSES">
        <id name="EmailAddressId" column="EMAIL_ADDRESS_ID" type="int">
            <generator class="native" />
        </id>
        <property name="CustomerAccountId" column="CUSTOMER_ACCOUNT_ID" type="string" />
        <property name="EmailAddressText" column="EMAIL_ADDRESS_TX" type="string" />
        <property name="EmailAddressTypeId" column="EMAIL_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID" type="int" />
        <property name="EmailAddressTypeIdInternal" column="EMAIL_ADDRESS_TYPE_ID_INTERNAL" type="int" />

    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: How are you dealing with sessions, and the session factory, from your application?

Comment: How many results is the query returning?  There is a difference between running the query and seeing results immediately in a SQL tool, vs retrieving ALL the results and loading them into objects.

Comment: I'm using 1 session per http request. Session factory is created once for the life of the app.

Comment: The query is returning 2 results, with 2 other results on a many to one join. If I run this join directly against Oracle, I get full results in under 1 second.

Comment: So when you say it's taking "an extremely long time", how long do you mean?  Also, is it just slow the first time (while NHibernate loads up and builds its runtime code), or everytime?

Comment: Are you creating a session for each call? You should use Spring or some other framework to manage your sessions for you, so that you don't have to create a new one each time.

Comment: The same query that would normally run in under a second takes up to 15 seconds. I've never experienced this when running against SQL Server, that's why I thought there might be something wrong w/ my Oracle config.

Comment: I'm creating a session per http request, using Jeff Palermo's method:
http://jeffreypalermo.com/blog/use-this-nhibernate-wrapper-to-keep-your-repository-classes-simple/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider using this tool for "debugging NHibernate"
[NHibernate Query Analyzer](http://ayende.com/projects/nhibernate-query-analyzer.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your connection pool is sufficiently large. Also, if you try debugging your code, you should be able to see where Hibernate is spending the majority of its time. It may be with processing the results, as someone commented earlier, especially if you have cascading relationships. If you do, try running those queries using subselect instead of lazy=false or fetch=join, as that will likely be significantly faster.